# Something similar to Nicos Weg but for french

Tags: ressources

My friend showed me Nico's Weg produced by Deutsche Welle and it is a very well defined and structured lesson program. (https://learngerman.dw.com/en/overview). I was wondering if there is a similar french resource like that.

I know there is https://apprendre.tv5monde.com/en and https://www.newsinslowfrench.com/french-for-beginners, but the way that it is organized seems confusing and I'm not sure if there is even a placement test for people who may be in A2 or B1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I know I think would be the [DELF](http://www.ciep.fr/delf-tout-public/exemples-des-sujets) - a certification of French language abilities

> **DELF** for short, is a certification of French-language abilities for non-native speakers of French administered by the International Centre for French Studies (Centre international d'études pédagogiques, or CIEP) for France's Ministry of Education.

Others non-official alternatives if needed :

- [france-langue.com](https://www.france-langue.com/french-levels/)
- [lawlessfrench](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/faq/lessons-by-level/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I think the best one out of the 3 is lawless french, although it its a paid service to get the full benefits. I'll try the free tier of lawless french and see how it is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the best if the DELF. If you're looking for a French language school in France I can recommend you this one : https://www.cia-france.com/
there are some lessons about DELF.

good luck

Comment: Bienvenue sur FSE.  What kind of resource is the program? I'm not sure if a study abroad enterprise answers the question, and I would encourage more accessible resources or information.